# can't edit permissions of directory after changing them using "sudo chmod 444 etc"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, chmod

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-31-virtual x86_64) and changed the permissions of the "etc" directory to 444 (sudo chmod 444 etc). I now cant change the permissions to anything else and am receiving the following message:

```
$ sudo chmod 777 etc
sudo: unable to open /etc/sudoers: Permission denied
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
```

I've tried to change to root user and change the permissions but I am prompted for a password which I was never asked to set, and am presented with this message:

```
$ su
Password:
su: Authentication failure
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should boot into "Ubuntu recovery mode" and change permissions back to /etc to 755:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/115358/changed-etc-permission-in-oneiric-ubuntu11-10-by-using-sudo-chmod-665-etc

Answer (score 0):

Reboot into single-user mode and fix the permissions on /etc from there.

Answer (score 0):

You've changed the permissions of the folder where the sudo's configuration files are located.

Try looking [here. This person had a similar problem.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152038/accidently-blocked-access-to-sudoers-d-whilst-trying-to-change-ushare-config)